# Measure HTML5 Canvas VS CSS3 performances on video effects

Tags: javascript, css, performance, html5-canvas, html5-video

I want to show a MediaStream from the camera back to the user.

I'm using a Canvas and the `drawImage` method to render the stream.

I need to flip and blur the image.

I want to understand if it's more performant to apply the `blur` and `scale` effects to the canvas using [CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) OR using CSS3 `transform.rotate()` and `filter: blur()` applied to the canvas element.

For context i'm inside a React app, but i don't think this is relevant.

To clarify my question is not "which one is better" (although suggestions are welcome) but it's: How would you measure the performances in order to make the best decision?

I can open chrome's `console>performance monitor` but it only gives me a live view of the CPU usage, i don't have a way to get the average through time and it's not consistent.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to monitor cpu usage (it can only retrieve the number of cpu cores in use) using browser js.

Comment: I think you need to 'go outside' your application to monitor over time as you need. Also you may want to look at GPU as well as CPU usage. Depends on your system but on Windows you could try the in-built task manager.